# Mabox-gl-js Marker translated position

Tags: javascript, mapbox-gl-js, mapbox-marker

I'm trying to use https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/#marker

```
const el = document.createElement('div');
el.className = 'marker';

const marker = new mapboxgl.Marker(el, {
  color: '#FFFFFF',
  draggable: true,
  offset: [0, 0],
})
  .setLngLat([0, 0])
  .addTo(this.map);
```

Which is connected to map:

```
this.map = new mapboxgl.Map({
  container: this.mapEl,
  center: [this.props.longitude, this.props.latitude],
  zoom: this.props.zoom,
  maxZoom: 17,
  pitch: this.props.pitch || 0,
  bearing: this.props.bearing || 0,
  style: getStyleByTheme(this.props.theme),
  preserveDrawingBuffer: true,
  attributionControl: false,
});
```

The problem is that the marker position is being 'translated' with huge values: `transform: translate(-50%, -50%) translate(225173px, 75290px);`

By debugging this calculation I found out that the problem is occuring at this line: https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-js/blob/e0c4d4679d06be7c0f51970b26a184f8d9ed6d5b/src/ui/marker.js#L338

So I went further:

```
this.map.project(marker.getLngLat())._add(marker.getOffset())
```

returns `{x: 225173.2033574923, y: 75289.74831606582}`

And by removing function `_add` call and outputting the value of `this.map.project(marker.getLngLat())` I get the same value.

So, this actually happens here: https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-js/blob/e0c4d4679d06be7c0f51970b26a184f8d9ed6d5b/src/ui/map.js#L616

Which leads me to https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-js/blob/7b4be8d247c7351df83316eed0f8d20d3a184722/src/geo/transform.js#L314

Ohh my, I'm lost now

What could be the issue here? Is it the Mapbox-gl-js, my map setup or event html structure?

Please help. :)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i figured it out - It was totally my fault!

As documentation says here - https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/#map#project
"Returns a Point representing pixel coordinates, relative to the map's container, that correspond to the specified geographical location."

I was using `.setLngLat([0, 0])` but the map actually pointed to different location.

By using, the same LngLat as the map is centered with, I fixed the issue. :)